# How to navigate to another page on onRowSelect

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am using Primefaces 3.0. I have a datatable with selectionMode single as shown below:

```
 <p:dataTable  id="paySumm" var="PSummRow" 
 value="#{beanPySummary.PySummariesModel}" 
 selection="#{beanPySummary.selectedPySummary}" selectionMode="single" paginator="true" 
 rows="15" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
 {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink}"  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,25,35" >

 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{beanPySummary.onRowSelect}" />
```

I have some business logic in the method onRowSelect and then I navigate to another page.

```
public String onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
   ......
   ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler =
   getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler(); 
   configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("MoreDetail?faces-redirect=true
   return  "";
```

I have some data that I would like to pass as parameters to MoreDeatils with includeViewParam. I can define those as f:ViewParam in MoreDeatils.xhtml. I am not sure if I need to use ManagedProperty annotation and at the same time define those params as hidden fields on my datatable page. Here I need advise and directions.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just send a redirect by `ExternalContext#redirect()`. The data which you'd like to send along needs to be set in the query string of the URL.

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws IOException {
    String field1 = URLEncoder.encode(this.field1, "UTF-8");
    String field2 = URLEncoder.encode(this.field2, "UTF-8");
    String field3 = URLEncoder.encode(this.field3, "UTF-8");
    String url = "MoreDetail.xhtml?field1=" + field1 + "&field2=" + field2 + "&field3=" + field3;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
}
```

Please note that (ajax) action listener methods are supposed to return `void`.

Comment: Thanks BalucsC. You are great not just beacuse you answered my question but for taking the pain and helping others.  Yes, I had void on onRowSelect method but I had noticed that it was calling the constructor twice. So I added String as return parameter then it stopped behaving that way. I am not sure why it stooped and I am also not sure why it was calling teh constructor twice as I had obsereved that in the debug mode. I am sure you can explain.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi BalusC, please bear with my ignorance. I am not sure how do I send my code with comments so I am just trying to explain here. Everything works fine which is in onRowSelect method except it opens up a File Download dialouge box for MoreDetails instead of loading that page. I can post my code under new post if you want. Also, I still need f ViewParm in my MoreDeatl xhtml? Thanks.

Comment: The example in my answer assumes that you've mapped `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`. If you've mapped it on a different URL pattern such as `*.jsf`, then you should of course change the redirect URL accordingly. E.g. `MoreDetai.jsf` instead of `MoreDetail.xhtml` (or better, change the URL pattern to `*.xhtml` so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works after changing to 'MoreDetail.jsf'. Only issue I am having is that only first parameter is being populated. Should I post a new messgae with code? I am asking as I am new but feel that will make more sense. I am going to post another message with subject -Navigate with Get parameters not getting all params. Thanks you BalusC for your patience and help.

Comment: Not populated, where? In the URL? Or in the target view/bean? Are you sure that you URL-encoded the individual parameter values as shown in my answer? Otherwise it would result in an invalid URL format.

Comment: The URL is being populated correctly. I saw that in the debug mode. I just posed another message. Thanks! Peter.